Missing app jar files in contents directory of Widlfly 31 VFS deployment location
We are migrating from Wildfly 30.0.1.FINAL to 31.0.1.FINAL.
In 30.0.1.FINAL all the application libraries were copied to %wildfly-31.0.1.Final%\standalone\tmp\vfs\deployment\deployment90110bdf73e52ecf\contact.jar-c26da1d272c45e0d on start of the server.
But in 31.0.1.FINAL it just creates a empty folder inside %wildfly-31.0.1.Final%\standalone\tmp\vfs\deployment\deployment90110bdf73e52ecf\contact.jar-6fa846a7d1d310c5\contents
JDK used is openjdk-17.0.2. Unfortunatley i couldn't see any error in server log also.

You should redeploy your application, not copy the tmp directory.

Yes, tmp dir is deleted before deployment.

Did you removed the deployment tag from your standalone.xml before restarting ?

I don't see deployment tag.

@JamesR.Perkins any idea what's wrong?

How are you deploying your application?


copied ear file (unzipped) in $WILDFLY_HOME/standalone/deployments folder. 2. start server with standalone.sh from $WILDFLY_HOME/bin. 3. Before each deployment data, log,tmp directories are deleted. Please find standalone.xml for reference. https://pastebin.com/WbX9iMyp


Have you tried deploying through a management API like the web console or CLI? That is the preferred way of deploying. The README.txt has some notes as to why it's preferred.

Tried with management web console and it's same issue. Empty directory (standalone\tmp\vfs\deployment\deployment164ee2c4cec73b31) with application jar file names. app jars are missing in these directories

@JamesR.Perkins I enabled wildfly debug logs but couldn't found the error. Any idea how can i debug this?? Somehow i need to have all my libs in tmp vfs deployment location. Thanks! Please suggest

I'm not sure I follow. What is it you're trying to read from the directory? The tmp directory is not meant to be read by applications.

@JamesR.Perkins We use reflection to filter classes. Reflection Scan and VFS to create directory to get from VFS location

and then our impl for createDir `VirtualFile content;
try {
content = VFS.getChild(url.toURI());
} catch (Throwable e) {
throw new ReflectionsException("could not open url connection as VirtualFile [" + url + "]", e);
}
    Vfs.Dir dir = null;
    try {
        dir = createDir(new java.io.File(content.getPhysicalFile().getParentFile(), content.getName()));
    } catch (IOException e) { /*continue*/ }` So basically we deal with VFS tmp location to get classes. Hope I conveyed


The tmp directory is not meant to be used like that. The org.jboss.vfs module is marked as private and also not meant to be used outside of WildFly itself. It's much better to get an InputStream to the resource, then trying to use the VirtualFile Something like getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/some-resource").

same issue on Widfly 32.
Probleme solved by https://issues.redhat.com/browse/DROOLS-7608
Upgrade drools in 7.75.0-SNAPSHOT or patch directly your jar with  org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.ClasspathKieProject
There is no final release provided at this time.
Regards.
